# pjsip(PJDroid) Video call Issue

Tags: crash, fatal-error, pjsua2

`\`1. I have open this project and update some latest library then run after i have check Android 11 then i have found working proper
but if when i cancel the call then i my application crash the crash error is :-

hangup: Title: pjsua_call_hangup(id, prm.statusCode, param.p_reason, param.p_msg_data)
Code: 171140
Description: INVITE session already terminated (PJSIP_ESESSIONTERMINATED)
Location: ../src/pjsua2/call.cpp:716  and another side  if when  i have reject the call then also my application crash and the crash error is

- ```
  hangup: Title: pjsua_call_hangup(id, prm.statusCode, param.p_reason, param.p_msg_data)
  Code:        171140
  Description: INVITE session already terminated (PJSIP_ESESSIONTERMINATED)
  Location:    ../src/pjsua2/call.cpp:716
  ```
- ```
  Title:    pjsua_call_hangup(id, prm.statusCode, param.p_reason, param.p_msg_data)
  Code:        70009
  Description: Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT)
  Location:    ../src/pjsua2/call.cpp:716
  ```

  2.    I have check another Device Android 9 and 12 then video preview is not show .

  3.    Some times crash the application the crash Error
- ```
  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9574 (.pjdroid.sample), pid 9574 (.pjdroid.sample)
  ```
- ```
  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x18 in tid 24149 (Thread-313), pid 23869(.pjdroid.sample)
  ```
- ```
  #16 pc 00000000002112aa  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app           /~~2vTCBX_UVK3ONaQKPgJbzw==/com.pjdroid.sample-KwbicUtdG5xwFLN2zNamJQ==/base.apk] (com.pjdroid.sample.CallActivity.updateVideoWindow+198)
  ```
- ```
  #19 pc 00000000002111c4  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~fFbe8cuPaZdFi9XQZOJ_yQ==/com.pjdroid.sample- 9kzZI7Okj_F2BA8Z0ePY8g==/base.apk](com.pjdroid.sample.CallActivity.updateVideoWindow)
  ```

fun makeCall(view: View) {
if (buddyListSelectedIdx == -1) return

```
    if (currentCall != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current id  already in call.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }
    if (buddyListSelectedIdx >= 0) {
        buddyListView!!.getItemAtPosition(buddyListSelectedIdx) as HashMap<*, *>

        val call = MyCall(account, -1)
        val prm = CallOpParam(true)
        try {

            if (buddy_uri.isNotEmpty()) {
                call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("makeCallError", "makeCall: " + e.message)
            call.delete()
            return
        }
        currentCall = call
        showCallActivity()
    }
}
```

```
  fun hangupCall(view: View?) {
        handler_ = null
        finish()
        if (MainActivity.currentCall != null) {
            val prm = CallOpParam()
            Log.d("hangupCallPrm1", "hangupCall: ${prm.statusCode} // $prm /?/${MainActivity.currentCall}")
            prm.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_DECLINE
            try {
                Log.d("hangupCallPrm", "hangupCall: "+prm.statusCode+"//"+prm.sdp+"//"+prm)
                MainActivity.currentCall?.hangup(prm)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("hangupCallError", "hangupCall: "+e.message)
            }
        }
    }
```